# JQuery Widgets - Remembering Position (Cookies)

Tags: jquery, cookies

So I have this script from NetTuts that I've modified and it's fully working in the sense that the widgets can now be moved around the column. What I need now is for it to save the widget location using jQuery.cookie so when the page refreshes, the widgets are in the correct order.

Sadly, I have absolutely no idea where to even begin with this one! I have some experience with jQuery.cookie saving whether the widgets are opened or closed but I'm not sure where to stick it in this jQuery code so it remembers the order of the widgets.

The JQuery code is here:

http://pastebin.com/di94EaGR

And you can see the widgets working on here:

http://dev.evaske.com/HXWP/

Thanks in advance for any input :)

Comment: I would save a cookie for the order either when it is changed or when the user closes the window.

Comment: I can't see that script getting an order from anywhere though. How would I go about so it first of all has an order so I can save it to the cookie?

Comment: Oh, saving an order would be easy by querying the `ul` that contains them and storing the `li` order, as for interacting with the script that lays them out, can't help you there. You could simply re-arrange them once they're loaded.

Comment: I guess I'd first need it to set an ID to each li depending on their position in the list?

Comment: You could steal the header text and use that to identify them, or you could try and get the id of the toggle div, (ex: "toggle-wiki"). Using the position in the list has a problem sorting if you ever add/remove widgets, using text has a problem recognizing unchanged widgets if you ever rename any.